# In Unity, how can I get the editor to show my enum property with custom setter?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have GameObject that I would like to render differently based on a given value. The way I chose to do this is the create an enum of the valid values, and a custom setter.

The problem however, is that it won't display in the Unity editor.

My intention is to be able to change the value via dropdown in the editor, and have the SetIcon() function be called, so that the GameObject renders correctly in the IDE. SerializeField doesn't seem to help. Is there a solution to this? I have Odin if that has anything that might help?

```
public enum Balls {BaseBall, Basketball, Football}

[field: SerializeField] public Balls ball
{
    get => ball;
    set
    {
        ball = value;
        SetIcon(ball);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also just use [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) and check for changes there ..

Answer (score 0):

With Odin, you can do this way:

```
[SerializeField, OnValueChanged("SetIconBall")]
private Balls _ball;

public Balls ball
{
    get => _ball;
    set
    {
        _ball = value;
        SetIconBall();
    }
}

void SetIconBall()
{
    SetIcon(_ball);
}
```

Note that [OnValueChanged](https://odininspector.com/attributes/on-value-changed-attribute) is called only when there is an inspector change. Not whith script, this is why I kept the setter in my example.